# Extract a worksheet from Excel retaining data values not references

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that contains about a dozen sheets. One sheet is called "Summary", and most of the data in it is either a reference to another sheet ( ='Pre-Survey'!C10 ) or a label ( =ShipName ).

My client wants me to email him *just* the Summary page as a one sheet Excel workbook. If I use 'Move or Copy a Sheet' to make a copy of the sheet as a new book, the cells still have references in them ( =("path\1234-Titanic.xlsx"!ShipName) ), whereas I want it to simply contain "Titanic".

How do I make the new sheet with the data being fixed at the value from the full workbook so I can email it to someone else and they don't get a bunch 0f ='REF'! errors?

I tried using 'break links', but it didn't help.

Richard

Comment: Did you try copy and paste `values` under the paste-special? The other option would be to convert the `Summary` tab into PDF and to pass it on - is that acceptable?

Comment: Paste into what? I want to copy the entire sheet, formatting and all. Paste Values would just copy across bare text / numbers, destroying things like column layouts.   Sending as a .pdf is how I've done it in the past. Now the client wants an Excel sheet :-(

Comment: Sorry to push this further. Copy-`paste-special` values and then use format painter to bring all the formatting back - Would it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

- Right-click the summary sheet
- select Move or Copy
- click "Create a copy"
- Select "New Book" in the "To book" drop-down and hit OK.

At this point the formulas will still be there.

- Select all with Ctrl-A and use Ctrl-C to copy
- Open the Paste Special dialog and paste as Values. There are half a dozen different approached to "Paste Special". If you need help finding them, pipe up.

Now the formulas will be replaced with the values, all formatting is intact and the sheet is in a new workbook that can be emailed easily.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct (prasanna); here is what they are saying in more detail:

Make a new blank sheet. Return to sheet you want to copy. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. Go to the new sheet, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, immediately followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (by itself), followed by <kbd>E</kbd> (again by itself).

Those are the shortcut keys and sequence to do a 'Paste Special Value and Source Formatting'. There are menu options to do exactly the same thing, as another answer described; but either way you are doing the same thing and getting the same result. Key strokes tend to be easier to describe than menu options, particularly when the menus change rev. to rev. in MS office.